# Role based access control of Mean stack web app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, role-based-access-control

I am working on a mean stack web application which contains differential access based upon the logged user's role. there are few different roles such as **admin**, **govt**, **volunteer** etc.

**1. how to manage the front end based upon the role?**

currently i am setting global flags such as isAdmin, isVolunteer, isGovt etc for each role and based upon their value, i am able to show different UI using `data-ng-if = "Global.isAdmin"`

Is this aproach is correct. if not please suggest the correct way to handle UI.

**2. how to manage the back-end and redirect the route if the user did'n have authorization?**

currently i am trying to use **angular-permission** and **rbac** but still unable to use these successfully in my application.
can anyone tell me the best practice for **role based access control for mean stack web app**.

while trying to use the **angular-permission**, i was unable to link the created roles to route file.

this is role module.

```
angular.module('mean.users', ['permission'])
.run(['permission', 'Global', '$q',
    function(Permission, Global, $q) {
        console.log('not anonumous');
        Permission
            .defineRole('anonymous', function(stateParams) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                if (Global.user) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferred.reject();
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            })
            .defineRole('admin', function(stateParams) {
                if (Global.isAdmin) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferred.reject();
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            })
            .defineRole('govt', function(stateParams) {
                if (Global.isGovt) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferred.reject();
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            })
            .defineRole('volunteer', function(stateParams) {
                if (Global.isVolunteer) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferred.reject();
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            });

    }
]);
```

how to link above configoured roles in route file

```
$stateProvider
        .state('create user', {
            url: '/users/create',
            templateUrl: 'users/views/create.html',
            resolve: {
                loggedin: checkLoggedin
            }
        })
        .state('all users', {
            url: '/users/list',
            templateUrl: 'users/views/list.html',
            data: {
                permissions: {
                     only: ['admin'],
                    redirectTo: 'home'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('show user', {
            url: '/users/:userId/view',
            templateUrl: 'users/views/view.html',
            resolve: {
                loggedin: checkLoggedin
            }
        })
        .state('edit user', {
            url: '/users/:userId/edit',
            templateUrl: 'users/views/edit.html',
            data: {
                permissions: {
                     only: ['admin']
                }
            }
        })
        .state('myprofile', {
            url: '/users/:userId/me',
            templateUrl: 'users/views/myprofile.html',
            resolve: {
                loggedin: checkLoggedin
            }

        });
```

Comment: @JonSamwell I guess it's good to provide a very brief answer, at least conceptual and then refer to your post inmediatly ;)

Answer (score 0):

From your code samples I guess you are using mean.io.

This is my approach to role based access control on the frontend, in mean.io.

First of all, I add the roles to some users, so that they exist in the database and I can use them.

```
$ mean user a@example.com --addRole production
$ mean user b@example.com --addRole sales
```

Then, I have 2 routes to add to the menu. In app.js of my custom module I filter this routes by role, so that the link isn't shown to other roles:

```
Report.menus.add({
  roles: ['production'],
  title: 'Production reports',
  link: 'production reports'
});
Report.menus.add({
  roles: ['sales'],
  title: 'Sales reports',
  link: 'sales reports'
});
```

Of course, this is not enough to restrict access in the frontend. You could easily point to http://localhost:3000/#!/report/sales and you would see the sales report whether you have the sales role or not.

The trick comes in the public/routes/report.js file of my custom module, where I filter the views by role.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.report').config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {
    // Check if user has role
    var checkUserRole = function(role, $q, $timeout, $http, $location) {
      // Initialize a new promise
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // Make an AJAX call to check if the user is logged in and get user data including roles
      $http.get('/loggedin').success(function(user) {
        // Authenticated
        if (user !== '0' && (user.roles.indexOf(role) > -1 || user.roles.indexOf('admin') > -1)) $timeout(deferred.resolve);

        // Not Authenticated
        else {
          $timeout(deferred.reject);
          $location.url('/auth/login');
        }
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    $stateProvider.state('report', {
      url: '/report',
      templateUrl: 'report/views/index.html'
    })
    .state('production reports', {
      url: '/report/production',
      templateUrl: 'report/views/production.html',
        resolve: {
          loggedin: function($q, $timeout, $http, $location) {
                return checkUserRole('production', $q, $timeout, $http, $location)
            }
        }
    })
    .state('sales reports', {
      url: '/report/sales',
      templateUrl: 'report/views/sales.html',
        resolve: {
          loggedin: function($q, $timeout, $http, $location) {
                return checkUserRole('sales', $q, $timeout, $http, $location)
            }
        }
    });
  }
]);
```

In case the user is unauthenticated, he is re-directed to the login page. If he has the wrong role, he is redirected to the home page.

This approach is based on the articles module. Hope it helps.